# Отладка задачи Yii2 queue

Tags: yii2

Решил для рассылки писем использовать yii2-queue.

```
 <?php
namespace app\models;
use yii\base\BaseObject;
use app\models\Newsletter;
use app\models\NewsletterQuene;

class NewsLetterJob extends BaseObject implements \yii\queue\JobInterface
{
  public $newsLetterId;

    public function execute($queue)
    {

        $newsLetter = Newsletter::find()->where(['id' => 8])->one();
        $mails  = NewsletterQuene::find()->where(['status' => 1])->
        limit(\Yii::$app->params['newsLetterCount'])->all();
        $changeStatus = [];
        foreach ($mails as $mail){
            \Yii::$app->mailer->compose(
                'newsletter',
                [
                    'content' => $newsLetter->message,
                    'name' => $mail->name
                ]
            )
                ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['fromEmail'])
                ->setTo($mail->email)
                ->setSubject($newsLetter->subject)
                ->send();
            $mail->status = 2;
            $mail->save();
             $changeStatus[] = $mail->id;
        }
       NewsletterQuene::updateAll(['status' => 2], ['in', 'id', $changeStatus]);

    }
}
```

вот Job

Создаю очередь так

```
  Yii::$app->queue->push(new NewsLetterJob([
            'newsLetterId' => $model->id,

        ]));
```

Запускаю в консоли,
очередь отрабатывает, 
ошибок нет,
но ничего не происходит, ни письма не отправляются, ни статус не меняется.
Вопрос.
Как отладить работу Joba
это же не контроллер, чтоб можно было 
  $this->stdout(var_dump(чтото);
написать.

вывода нет, и не понятно, то ли ошибка то ли что.
queue настроена на работу с db
она работает все хорошо, вижу задания, 
вижу что выполнены...

Comment: Можно попробовать в логи записать. Еще смотря как отправка происходит. На локалке надо в файлы письма писать.

Comment: да не про отправку речь, а про отладку самого джоба. Ну я его уже отладил, пришлось вызывать его из вэба, передавать туда данные, много чего менять. То есть костыли... Неважно что он делает, в моем случае просто пара синтаксических ошибок была. Но очередь отрабатывает без ругани, и не понятно как увидеть что не так. И в логах (runtime/logs) нет логирования  работы этого джоба. Подскажите, как подключить логирование к нему, плиз.

Comment: Это смотря как запущен демон для прослушивания очереди. Если супервизор слушает, то в конфиге должна быть строка куда складывать логи `stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/yii-queue-worker.log` Плюс дебаг https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/debug.md Плюс логирование https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue/blob/master/docs/guide/usage.md

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался. Логирование подключил. Запускаю из вэба. Но все равно остались вопросы,  я у вас на форуме спрошу лучше. Более развёрнуто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 php yii queue/run --verbose=1 --isolate=0
```

`verbose=1`- для детального вывода в консоль

`isolate=0` - будет работать в одном потоке и будет возможность работать с xdebug (ставить точки останова)